# Add class to parent and sibling elements if element with specific class is found

Tags: jquery

Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <label class="label">Label Text</label>
    <div class="error">Error Message</div>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" class="input">
    </div>
    <div class="instructions">
        Instructions text
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, this is repeated for each form field, except that the `div.error` is only present for such rows as actually contain errors (validated serverside).

If the `row` includes a `div.error`, then I want to use jQuery to assign additional classes to the `.row`, `.label`, `.input`, and `.instructions` classes -- but ONLY for the `div.row` that includes the error.

(I realize jQuery is not the best way to handle this, but all I have under the circumstances.)

I've tied my brain in knots for the past two hours and just can't figure it out, so would appreciate any answers on how this can be accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it via:

```
$('.row').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('.error').length > 0) {
    $('.label, .input, .instructions',this).add(this).addClass('foo')
  }
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hxqfw3r8/)**

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I needed, and pretty short and sweet, too!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a selector to find all of the `error` classes and iterate through each one using the [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). Within each iteration, you can then access the closest `<tr>` via the [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function and do what you need :

```
// Target your erroneous <div> elements
$('div.error').each(function(){ 
    // Add a specific class 'your-class' to each row that contains an error  
    $(this).closest('.row').addClass('your-class');
});
```

Likewise if you want to target additional fields under the `<tr>` element, you can do so within the `each()` function as well :

```
// Target your erroneous <div> elements
$('div.error').each(function(){ 
    // This is your current row
    var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
    // Find your instructions and do something
    $row.find('.instructions').doSomething();
    // Find your label and do something 
    $row.find('.label').doSomething();
    // Continue to your heart's content
});
```

**Example Snippet**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <label class="label">Label Text</label>
    <div class="error">Error Message</div>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" class="input">
    </div>
    <div class="instructions">
        Instructions text
    </div>
</div>
  <hr />
  <div class="row">
    <label class="label">Label Text</label>
    <div class="error">Error Message</div>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" class="input">
    </div>
    <div class="instructions">
        Instructions text
    </div>
</div>
  <hr />
  <div class="row">
    <label class="label">Label Text</label>
    <div></div>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" class="input">
    </div>
    <div class="instructions">
        Instructions text
    </div>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        // Target your erroneous <div> elements
        $('div.error').each(function(){ 
            // This is your current row
            var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
            // Find your instructions and do something
            $row.find('.instructions').css('color','red');
            // Find your label and do something 
            $row.find('.label').css('color','blue');
            // Continue to your heart's content
            $row.find('.input').css('color','green').val('Uh oh');
        });
      })
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.row .error').each(function () {
  $(this).siblings('.label, .instructions').addClass('.errorrow');
  $(this).siblings('.container').find('.input').addClass('.errorrow');
});
```

You would probably be better off to set a class to the .row and style or select elements from there, though:

```
/* jQuery */
$('.row .errorrow').parent().addClass('.errorrow');

/* CSS */
.row.error {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion to set the class to .row is what I'd prefer to do, but I'm working with Bootstrap and I want to be able to use the has-error class - which means certain elements within the .row need to have the classes that has-error targets.